# Is bridgeToObjectiveC is really needed?

Tags: ios, swift

Is `bridgeToObjectiveC()` really needed for conversion between Swift `String` to `NSString`? What is the behaviour of `bridgeToObjectiveC()`? As I have read many places there is no need and conversion to swift `String` to `NSString` is implicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type conversion between swift `String` to `NSString` is implicit if you are importing the `Foundation` framework.If you use `import Foundation` then there is no need to use `bridgeToObjectiveC()` for strings.From swift [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_40)

> Swift automatically bridges between the String type and the NSString
>   class. This means that anywhere you use an NSString object, you can
>   use a Swift String type instead and gain the benefits of both
>   types—the String type’s interpolation and Swift-designed APIs and the
>   NSString class’s broad functionality. For this reason, you should
>   almost never need to use the NSString class directly in your own code.
>   In fact, when Swift imports Objective-C APIs, it replaces all of the
>   NSString types with String types. When your Objective-C code uses a
>   Swift class, the importer replaces all of the String types with
>   NSString in imported API.
>
> To enable string bridging, just import Foundation.

But in some cases the default bridging will not work like you can not check length of string

```
var abcs = "somString"
abcs.length //will not work

abcs.bridgeToObjectiveC().length //you need call `bridgeToObjectiveC` explicitly
```

for this case default bridging will not work.

Comment: In Swift it is better to use `countElements(abcs)` or `abcs.utf16count` since they do not require bridging.

Comment: yes you can they are not `NSString` functions.I want to show in some cases we need to explicit define `bridgeToObjectiveC` as implicit casting may not work.

Comment: No problems with your code and answer. Just wanted to put it as a comment here so if beginners get here they can easily see how to work with strings.

Answer (score 0):

It's *supposed* to be implicit, but there are plenty of places where it's not. Strings, Arrays, and Dictionaries lack several of their Obj-C counterparts' scalar operations, such as `String.length`.

Answer (score 0):

bridgeToObjectiveC() not available in Swift 2.2

Instead use: _bridgeToObjectiveC()

for example:

```
var temp: String = "hello"
print(temp._bridgeToObjectiveC().length)
```